# How to display random numbers in jlabel?

Tags: java, random, awt, jlabel

I need how to Display Random number in JLabel Java I used

```
Random sum1 = new Random();

jLabel1.setText(random1);
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: My problem to write random number in jLabel

Comment: Have you read the manual page for `Random`?

Comment: Please add a complete example of what you have tried. Here we don't know what `random1` is, and `sum1` is not used. Also, you are actually asking two questions here: _How to generate a random number?_ and _How to display a number in a `JLabel`?_. Those two questions are not tightly related so it's better to ask them separately, or only ask the one which you have issues with. Nevertheless, both are quite trivial so it's probably why you are getting downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

`Random` is a class used to generate random numbers - you need to use it by calling one of its `nextWhatever` methods:

```
Random r = new Random();
jLabel1.setText(String.valueOf(r.nextInt());
```